# Filtering One column into Different Columns in one statement

Tags: migration, visual-foxpro

I need to

SELECT amount FROM table WHERE type='1' AND type='2' AND type'3'

Depending on the types, I need them to be pulled into different columns.

For example,

IF type=1 THEN amount1
IF type=2 THEN amount2
IF type=3 THEN amount3.

Is it possible to this in one statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways

SELECT

```
CASE WHEN `amount`='type 1' then `amount` end as `amount1`,

CASE WHEN `amount`='type 2' then `amount` end as `amount2`,

CASE WHEN `amount`='type 3' then `amount` end as `amount3`
```

FROM `db`.`tablename`;

Ex:

SELECT

```
CASE WHEN amount=1000 then amount end as amount1,

CASE WHEN amount=2000 then amount end as amount2,

CASE WHEN amount=3000 then amount end as amount3
```

FROM db.test;